# Angular ng-disabled for number form where input can be = 0

Tags: angularjs

I am working on a submit form and in order to make the form work optimally in IE I added ng-disabled to the submit button.

Example HTML

```
<form>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="form.name" required="">
    <input class="form-control" type="number" ng-model="form.amount" required="">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default form-control" ng-disabled="!form.name || !form.amount " >
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></span> Submit!
     </button>
</form>
```

The problem I'm getting is that I need to have a value of 0 be submitted but it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want your button to be disabled when the form is invalid. So give a name to your form (and your inputs):

```
<form name="myForm">
```

and use

```
ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid"
```

This is much cleaner: you don't have to add more conditions when you add fields to the form or other validators to your inputs.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly. Much more pretty too

Answer (score 0):

You should process in *ng-disabled* `form.name` as text and `form.amount` as number, but you are processing as boolean.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default form-control" ng-disabled="form.name.lenght === 0 || form.amount === 0" >
```

In your controller you have to declare var form:

```
$scope.form = {
   name: "",
   amount: 0
}
```

In addition, in *input type='number'* you can establish min number.

```
<input class="form-control" type="number" ng-model="form.amount" min="0" required>
```

I hope help you, but last line confuses me a bit.

Comment: The OP wants to be able to submit 0. Your suggestion disables the button if the amount is 0. And it enables it if the user hasn't entered anything in the field, which is supposed to be required.

Comment: Ok, then you should change for *form.amount < 0*. Anyway, as the saying JB Nizet, the correct way is to use $invalid. I focused in disable button, not in validation form.